# Can't call function through proxy contract in ethers.js

Tags: polygon, defi, proxy-contracts

I'm trying to call in node.js a function(depositLPandStake) from this conctract "0x4E4De8594aD39cd21971775504702d4B00a1451E", seems like this is an implementation contract from that proxy "0xc9Ae7Dac956f82074437C6D40f67D6a5ABf3E34b".
To create contract instance I'm using proxy address and ABI from implementation contract.

Here is a code:

```
async function runPenrose() {
  const gasPrice = await getGasPrice();
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_SECRET, web3Provider);

  const PenroseCommunication = new ethers.Contract(
    PenroseProxy,
    PenroseContractABI,
    web3Provider
  );

  const penroseContract = PenroseCommunication.connect(wallet);
  const tokenAmount = await getTokenBalanceWallet(PoolToken);

  return await penroseContract.functions
    .depositLpAndStake(DystopiaPoolAddress, tokenAmount, {
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
      gasLimit: BigNumber.from("500000"),
    })
    .call();
}
```

And I have this error:

```
.depositLpAndStake(DystopiaPoolAddress, tokenAmount, {
     ^

TypeError: penroseContract.functions.depositLpAndStake is not a function
```

Nevertheless polygonscan can find implementation contract and all functions could be used in "write as Proxy" panel, but for some reason I can't do the same in ethers.js

**Edit**: I solved the problem. The reason is that called function has 2 different implimentation depending on arguments: with argument "amount" or without it, so I trimmed down the ABI, removed unnecessary function implimentation and it's started to work properly.

Comment: You are using etherjs so the call should be `penroseContract.depositLpAndStake(...)`, without the `functions` (that is a web3js thing).

Answer (score 1):

Penrose (0xc9Ae7Dac) is a proxy contract and by default, Penrose uses UserProxyInterface (0x4E4De859) implementation whenever an unrecognized function is called. This being said, the Penrose Contract does not implement the function `depositLPandStake` but happens to be implemented by UserProxyInterface (0x4E4De859). Thus the Penrose ABI does not define the function `depositLpAndStake`

Replacing Penrose's ABI by UserProxyInterface could do the trick:

```
 const PenroseCommunication = new ethers.Contract(
    PenroseProxy,
    UserProxyInterfaceABI,
    web3Provider
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I already use in my case UserProxyInterfaceABI from here(0x4E4De859), and adress from PenroseProxy(0xc9Ae7Dac), and still have the same error.